# How to sleep inbetween parallel downloading using Xargs with wget command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget, xargs

I'm trying to download multiple files using wget command. xrgs helps to download multiple files in parallel by redirecting the list of files links saved in a file. This is the command I'm using

```
cat file.txt | xargs -n 1 -p 10 wget -c
```

above command helps to download 10 files asynchronously, as I'm downloading using torrent doing multiple requests to download block the website from fetching the file. I get error as follow if I try to download more than 3 files

```
ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

Is there a way to sleep for a few seconds before starting the download of a new file? suppose for 1 batch as 10 download begins by delaying 5 seconds inbtwn these files or any way around I just trying to download files asynchronously

Comment: `suppose for 1 batch as 10 download begins by delaying 5 seconds` I do not understand that. You want to run 10 downloads in parallel, wait 5 seconds, then run another 10, then wait 5 seconds, then run another 10, then wait 5 seconds, etc?

Comment: @KamilCuk thats not a issue I want to delay inbetween the batch files itself. As I give multiple files to download at a once I get error as ERROR 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable